# How exaclty is defined an HSQLDB database into a Spring project? Who "read" the db-schema.sql table definitionfile?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-data, hsqldb

I am pretty new in **Spring** and I have the following doubt.

I have this **applicationContext.xml** configuration file that configure the beans for a model project that is imported into a **Spring MVC** application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties" />

    <context:spring-configured />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.packtpub.springmvc.chocolatestore">
        <context:exclude-filter expression=".*_Roo_.*"
            type="regex" />
        <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"
            type="annotation" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="true" />
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000" />
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3" />
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000" />
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven 
        transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:META-INF/sql/db-test-data.sql" />
    </jdbc:initialize-database>
</beans>
```

As you can see this file configure the beans related to the data access and in particular it contain this bean definition:

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:META-INF/sql/db-test-data.sql" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

that define an **HSQLDB** database that is configured by this file: **db-test-data.sql** that simply insert some test data into the database table each time that the application is started:

insert into category (id, name, description) values (default, 'Truffles', 'Truffles')
insert into category (id, name, description) values (default, 'Belgian Chocolates', 'Belgian Chocolates')
insert into product (id, category, description, featured, image_path, price, name) values (default, 1, 'Dark Chocolate Truffle', true, 'img_path', 20, 'Dark Chocolate Truffle')
insert into product (id, category, description, featured, image_path, price, name) values (default, 1, 'White Chocolate Truffle', true, 'img_path', 20, 'White Chocolate Truffle')
insert into product (id, category, description, featured, image_path, price, name) values (default, 1, 'Milk Chocolate Truffle with Cocoa', true, 'img_path', 20, 'Milk Chocolate Truffle with Cocoa')
insert into product (id, category, description, featured, image_path, price, name) values (default, 1, 'Almond Truffle', true, 'img_path', 20, 'Almond Truffle')

insert into product (id, category, description, featured, image_path, price, name) values (default, null, 'description', true, 'img_path', 20, 'Peanut Clusters')
insert into product (id, category, description, featured, image_path, price, name) values (default, null, 'description1', true, 'img_path1', 20, 'English Toffee')
insert into product (id, category, description, featured, image_path, price, name) values (default, null, 'description', true, 'img_path', 20, 'Dark Chocolate (Box)')
insert into product (id, category, description, featured, image_path, price, name) values (default, null, 'description1', true, 'img_path1', 20, 'Glace Apricot')

```
insert into customer (id, email, first_name, last_name, password, phone, name) values (default, 'test@test.com', 'First', 'Last', 'test', '1234567890', 'testtest')
insert into customer (id, email, first_name, last_name, password, phone, name) values (default, 'test1@test.com', 'First', 'Last', 'test', '1234567890', 'adminUser')
insert into customer (id, email, first_name, last_name, password, phone, name) values (default, 'test1@test.com', 'First', 'Last', 'test', '1234567890', 'shopOwner')
insert into customer (id, email, first_name, last_name, password, phone, name) values (default, 'charlie@packtpub.com', 'Charlie', 'Bucket', 'charlie', '1234567890', 'charlie')
```

My doubt is: the **db-test-data.sql** contains only the test data that are inserted into the in memory database tables but don't contain any table definition. Into my project I also find another sql file named **db-schema.sql** that contains the tables definition:

```
alter table product drop constraint FK_19w9vgbbv4qs6m0tkucs9ad0c
alter table product drop constraint FK_19w9vgbbv4qs6m0tkucs9ad0c
alter table purchase drop constraint FK_rf4yj0t3bq1f42596a7v71l1c
alter table purchase drop constraint FK_rf4yj0t3bq1f42596a7v71l1c
alter table purchaseitem drop constraint FK_5ta318a5vltt62onwwyv79rks
alter table purchaseitem drop constraint FK_5ta318a5vltt62onwwyv79rks
alter table purchaseitem drop constraint FK_1y3h3hbsrr3fbpuqbfj6ogoi2
alter table purchaseitem drop constraint FK_1y3h3hbsrr3fbpuqbfj6ogoi2

drop table category if exists
drop table customer if exists
drop table product if exists
drop table purchase if exists
drop table purchaseitem if exists
create table category (id bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1), description varchar(700) not null, name varchar(100) not null, version integer, primary key (id))
create table customer (id bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1), email varchar(255) not null, first_name varchar(255), last_name varchar(255), name varchar(100) not null, password varchar(255) not null, phone varchar(20), version integer, primary key (id))
create table product (id bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1), description varchar(700) not null, featured boolean, image_path varchar(700), price double not null, product_name varchar(100) not null, version integer, category bigint, primary key (id))
create table purchase (id bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1), completed boolean, order_date timestamp not null, version integer, ordered_by bigint, primary key (id))
create table purchaseitem (id bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1), order_date timestamp not null, quantity integer not null, version integer, product bigint, purchase bigint, primary key (id))
alter table product add constraint FK_19w9vgbbv4qs6m0tkucs9ad0c foreign key (category) references category
alter table purchase add constraint FK_rf4yj0t3bq1f42596a7v71l1c foreign key (ordered_by) references customer
alter table purchaseitem add constraint FK_5ta318a5vltt62onwwyv79rks foreign key (product) references product
alter table purchaseitem add constraint FK_1y3h3hbsrr3fbpuqbfj6ogoi2 foreign key (purchase) references purchase
```

The thing that I can't understand is that into the **applicationContext.xml** configuration file I have a reference to the **db-test-data.sql** file but nothing related to the **db-schema.sql** that define my table (I have found no reference to this file in my project).

How is it possible? Who and where is called the **db-test-data.sql** file to create the table into the database? Is it automatically done by Spring? So it means that I have just to put the **db-schema.sql** file in my project and the DB is automatically created?

What am I missing? How exactly works?

Answer (score 0):

Not enough detail here. Perhaps you also have hibernate configured which has an option to automatically create the schema based on your @Entity classes?